# Android development on real device: API update

Tags: android, api, installation, android-api-levels

Today before lunch time I got the Samsung GT-i9250 Galaxy Nexus - Ice Cream Sandwich. We are going to use it to develop 3D Native Apps.

I did the usual step as you can see:

- connect USB
  then on terminal run the command line:

  ```
  $ adb devices
  List of devices attached 
  0149C6F617016002    device
  $ lsusb | grep 04e8
  Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
  ```
- Then setup the file:

  ```
  # nano /etc/udev/rules.d/91-android.rules
  SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTRS{idVendor}==”04e8″, SYMLINK+=”android_adb”, MODE=”0666″
  ```

Closed the file. Then:

```
     chmod 644 /etc/udev/rules.d/91-android.rules
     service udev restart
```

- Compile:

Next I compiled the program and tried to run it in the android smartphone. The compiler showed my Android device as connected through USB, and asked me to choose it to run the program. Then:

```
    Android Launch!
    adb is running normally.
    Performing android.app.NativeActivity activity launch
    Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
    ERROR: Application requires API version 15. Device API version is 14 (Android 4.0.2).
    Launch cancelled!
```

So, should my device be updated? How to do it?

Comment: change your mintarget sdkVersion in your manifest as 14.

Comment: You've compiled your application for Android 4.0.3, and your device has 4.0.2. You should edit your AndroidMaifest.xml, and set android:targetSdkVersion to 14

Comment: the Nexus seems to have no update to 4.0.3 available - meaning there is no way to upgrade the phone

Comment: thank you guys! setting manifest.xml as 14 made the software upload and run into the device.

Comment: I don't know... if I understood correctly, the android docs ask to target highest possible version and to use a compatibility pack for devices with lower apis

Comment: sometimes the newest API makes things crash due to some new bug still pending to get fixed. in such occasion, downgrading solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is self explanatory i believe . either set lower value for MinSdkVersion in manifest , or use device with suitable API version .

Comment: Thansk for the suggestion. Changing the AndroidManifest.xml to: <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="14" android:minSdkVersion="14"></uses-sdk> solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to develop applications for API level 15, [you will need to update your device to 4.0.3](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).

Another option is - if you're not using any features from API level 15, to just change your project down to API level 14 (Project/Properties/Android will let you choose any installed API level). That will allow the application to run on any Android 4.0 phone.

Comment: Good to know. Maybe I will also consider updating the device.